# Facebook sdk integration open mobile site login screen instead of asking permissions in IOS

Tags: ios, facebook

I have a strange problem with integrating Facebook SDK for IOS and it does not happen on all my devices. In my iPhone it works fine, but with my ipad it gives me the problem. I have a Share button in my app, and in my iPhone when I press it I get a screen that asks for permission and then the post is happened.

On my iPad, it open a screen where I should put the username and password, and it does not fetch them from the Facebook account already logged in.

Here is my code:

```
- (void)sharetoMyWall{
    if (!FBSession.activeSession.state == FBSessionStateCreatedTokenLoaded) {
        NSLog(@" first time access");
        [self openSession];
     } else if (!FBSession.activeSession.isOpen) {
         NSLog(@"active session is not open");
         [self openSession];
     }

    if (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen) {
     NSArray *permissions =
     [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"publish_stream", nil];

        if ([[[FBSession activeSession]permissions]indexOfObject:@"publish_actions"] == NSNotFound) {
            [[FBSession activeSession] requestNewPublishPermissions:permissions
                                             defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceFriends
                                             completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, NSError *error) {
                                                 //handle success + failure in block
                                                 [self postToMyWall];
                                             }];
            } else {
                [self postToMyWall];
            }
     }

- (void)openSession
{



    [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:nil
                                       allowLoginUI:YES
                                  completionHandler:
     ^(FBSession *session,
       FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {
         [self sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error];
     }];
}
```

What am I missing?

And another one question: Should the Facebook be logged in as "myname" from the Settings>Facebook or it just needs to be logged in. Because that is the only difference between my iPhone and my iPad. In my iPhone, I can see that that I am logged in from the settings whilst in the iPad I logged out from the settings (although I am logged in in the Facebook app itself)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this code

```
- (IBAction)facebookShareBtn_TouchUpInside:(UIButton *)sender
{
   //Ask for publish_actions permissions in context
        if ([FBSession.activeSession.permissions
             indexOfObject:@"publish_actions"] == NSNotFound) {
            // Permission hasn't been granted, so ask for publish_actions
            [FBSession openActiveSessionWithPublishPermissions:@[@"publish_actions"]
                                               defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceFriends
                                                  allowLoginUI:YES
                                             completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {
                                                 if (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen && !error) {
                                                     // Publish the story if permission was granted
                                                     [self publishStory];
                                                 }
                                             }];
        } else {
            // If permissions present, publish the story
            [self publishStory];
        }
}


    - (void)publishStory
    {
        NSMutableDictionary *params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Me Something", @"name",@"Think of it as your personal.So what are you waiting for.....!", @"description", @"http://support24hour.com/workplace2/askie/ic_launcher.png", @"picture", nil];

        [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/feed" parameters:params HTTPMethod:@"POST" completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error)
        {
             NSString *alertText;
             if (error) {
                 alertText = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                              @"error: domain = %@, code = %d",
                              error.domain, error.code];
             } else {
                 alertText = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                              @"Posted action, id: %@",
                              result[@"id"]];
             }
             // Show the result in an alert
             [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Result" message:alertText delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK!" otherButtonTitles:nil]show];
         }];
    }
```